# Cannot access Advanced Startup Options in Window 10 as it closes / crashes automatically

Tags: windows, windows-10

Needed to do get the Advanced Startup options within Windows 10 21H2 and for some reason the window opens and then hangs for a moment and then automatically closes / crashes.

This happens whether I try to invoke it directly from the start menu by searching for 'change advanced startup options' or if I go to `Settings` -> `Update & Security` and clicking `Recovery`.

The only way I can access the menu is to hold shift while selecting Restart from the Power menu.

This used to work fine as recently as a few weeks ago, but I can't figure out what's gone wrong.

I have executed the following and rebooted multiple times:

`chkdsk /f /v`

`sfc /scannow`

`dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`

Any suggestions?

I suppose I could try an in-place upgrade, but I've often had mixed results with in-place upgrades so wanted to check with other users here first.

Answer (score 0):

Running DISM and SFC is the basic set of repair steps. Since these have not work, the next repair is a Windows 10 Repair Install.

This is a repair and not necessarily an in-place upgrade.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

You can also make a USB Key and run Setup.exe on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

Try Keep Everything first. Your computer will come back the way you left it.

If Keep Everything does not work, the next steps (Keep Just Data and Keep Nothing) are more aggressive. Keep Nothing is like a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Not Attempting to answer, but I am not able to Comment.
In order to find out why the crash keeps happening, have you checked the event logs? Just FYI, that shouldn't happen and means that the system is not "stable", which why, I think, @John recommended a fresh install. Just being able to get to those options with a "workaround" still means you have an unstable system. I would backup any info I needed and reinstall Windows just like @John said.

Answer (score 0):

This particular issue turned out to be a Microsoft issue and I witnessed it across multiple systems in our business simultaneously.  It has now been resolved in a previous Windows update and should be part of KB5016616